# Unable to convert to datetime using pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, datetime, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file and convert it to a dataframe to be used as a time series.
The csv file is of this type:

```
         #Date      Time    CO_T1_AHU.01_CC_CTRV_CHW__SIG_STAT
0          NaN       NaN                                     %   
1          NaN       NaN  Cooling Coil Hydronic Valve Position   
2   2014-01-01  00:00:00                                     0   
3   2014-01-01  01:00:00                                     0   
4   2014-01-01  02:00:00                                     0   
5   2014-01-01  03:00:00                                     0   
6   2014-01-01  04:00:00                                     0
```

I read the file using:

```
df = pd.read_csv ('filepath/file.csv', sep=';', parse_dates = [[0,1]])
```

producing this result:

```
             #Date_Time   FCO_T1_AHU.01_CC_CTRV_CHW__SIG_STAT
0               nan nan                                     %   
1               nan nan  Cooling Coil Hydronic Valve Position   
2   2014-01-01 00:00:00                                     0   
3   2014-01-01 01:00:00                                     0   
4   2014-01-01 02:00:00                                     0   
5   2014-01-01 03:00:00                                     0   
6   2014-01-01 04:00:00                                     0
```

to continue converting string to datetime and using it as index:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.values[:,0])
df.set_index([df.columns[0]], inplace=True)
```

so i get this:

```
                      FCO_T1_AHU.01_CC_CTRV_CHW__SIG_STAT
#Date_Time                                                  
nan nan                                                 %   
nan nan              Cooling Coil Hydronic Valve Position   
2014-01-01 00:00:00                                     0   
2014-01-01 01:00:00                                     0   
2014-01-01 02:00:00                                     0   
2014-01-01 03:00:00                                     0   
2014-01-01 04:00:00                                     0
```

However, the pd.to_datetime is unable to convert to datetime. Is there a way of finding out what is the error?

Many thanks.
Luis

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Liam, it was "unable to parse naan"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string entry 'nan nan' cannot be converted using `to_datetime`, so replace these with an empty string so that they can now be converted to `NaT`:

```
In [122]:

df['Date_Time'].replace('nan nan', '',inplace=True)
df
Out[122]:
             Date_Time  index       CO_T1_AHU.01_CC_CTRV_CHW__SIG_STAT
0                           0                                     %   
1                           1  Cooling Coil Hydronic Valve Position   
2  2014-01-01 00:00:00      2                                     0   
3  2014-01-01 01:00:00      3                                     0   
4  2014-01-01 02:00:00      4                                     0   
5  2014-01-01 03:00:00      5                                     0   
6  2014-01-01 04:00:00      6                                        0
In [124]:

df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df

Out[124]:
            Date_Time  index       CO_T1_AHU.01_CC_CTRV_CHW__SIG_STAT
0                 NaT      0                                     %   
1                 NaT      1  Cooling Coil Hydronic Valve Position   
2 2014-01-01 00:00:00      2                                     0   
3 2014-01-01 01:00:00      3                                     0   
4 2014-01-01 02:00:00      4                                     0   
5 2014-01-01 03:00:00      5                                     0   
6 2014-01-01 04:00:00      6                                        0
```

**UPDATE**

Actually if you just set `coerce=True` then it converts fine:

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], coerce=True)
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum. I wonder if using the parameter coerce=True does the same effectively. (I am thinking that there may be more than one "nan" or other unparseable strings)

Comment: @user2564259 actually yes `coerce=True` works, not sure what else it handles though. I will add an update

Comment: Thanks Ed, now df type is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and df.index type is <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>

Comment: how to drop those `NaT` values after `coerce`?

Comment: `dropna` would do.

Comment: In 3.9 I get `TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coerce'`...